# Get Child of object that is not a transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject with a TextMeshProUGUI as a child, and I'm trying to create copies of this GameObject via script and then change the text of the TMP child. I have the parent GameObject successfully created, and I can see that the child is there, however using `GetChild()` only returns a transform object type, which doesn't have the method I need (specifically the text field).

```
public GameObject goGoalBtn; // this is in the variable declarations
//other stuff here

public void spawnGoalDisplay(string goalDispName, int goalDispType=0) {
  GameObject goGoalDisplay = (GameObject)Instantiate(goGoalBtn);

  // this works
  Transform newGoalDisplay = goGoalDisplay.transform.GetChild(0); 
  Debug.Log("newGoalDisplay: "+ newGoalDisplay.name);
  
  // this doesn't work
  TextMeshProUGUI newGoalDisplay = goGoalDisplay.transform.GetChild(0); 
  Debug.Log("newGoalDisplay: "+ newGoalDisplay.text); // this is what I need to read/write
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to change the child's object type to TextMeshProUGUI. Is it possible to set the type of the child object returned with `GetChild()` to something other than `Transform`? Or a different way to get the child of an object (I tried `goGoalDisplay.child(0)` but that didn't work either) that lets me set the object type?

I think I could possibly bypass this issue by instantiating the GameObject and then instatiate the TMP and then set it as a child of the parent GameObject, and destroy the first child, but that seems ... unnecessarily complex, so I'd like to use a better solution if one exists. I'm fairly new to C# and Unity3D and would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: TextMeshProUGUI newGoalDisplay =( TextMeshProUGUI) goGoalDisplay.transform.GetChild(0);

Comment: This gives me the error: `error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about either

```
TextMeshProUGUI newGoalDisplay  = goGoalDisplay.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
```

or diectly

```
TextMeshProUGUI newGoalDisplay  = goGoalDisplay.GetcomponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
```

Comment: Ok, this 2nd way works. Thanks!

Comment: @AliumBritt this means the component is not on the GetChild(0) but either further nested below or already on the `goGoalDisplay` itself (in which case you could also just use `goGoaldisplay.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>()`)

Comment: Hmmm, well it's directly under the `goGoalDisplay` object but `GetComponent()` doesn't seem to work. Not sure why not, but at least the `GetComponentInChildren()` is working for now.

Answer (score 0):

`transform.GetChild()` will return the Transform of that GameObject. if you want to access the `TextMeshProUGUI` component you could simply do the following,

```
TextMeshProUGUI newGoalDisplay = goGoalDisplay.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>;
```

Now I am assuming that the first child of your `goGoalDisplay` has `TextMeshProUGUI` component attached to it, otherwise it will throw a `null reference exception` when you will try to debug the text.

Comment: The child is the `TextMeshProUGUI`, so this seems to be going a level deeper. Maybe this would work if I made an empty object child of `goGoalDisplay` and then put the TMP inside it?

Comment: If the child is the `TextMeshProUGUI`, then `goGoalDisplay.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>` would work just fine.